# A Question About the Elliott-Natsume-Nest Proof of Bott Periodicity

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras

In Wegge-Olsen’s book *K-Theory and C$ ^{*} $-Algebras*, there is an outline of a proof of Bott Periodicity (the proof is due to George Elliott, Toshikazu Natsume and Ryszard Nest). The first step of the proof outline goes as follows:

> Suppose that there are natural transformations
>
> - $ \Phi^{0} $ from the $ K_{0} S $-functor to the $ K_{1} $-functor and
> - $ \Phi^{1} $ from the $ K_{1} S $-functor to the $ K_{0} $-functor,
>
> where $ S $ denotes the suspension functor. In other words, for every C$ ^{*} $-algebra $ \mathscr{A} $ (not necessarily unital), there are abelian-group homomorphisms
>   $$
> \Phi^{0}_{\mathscr{A}}: {K_{0}}(S(\mathscr{A})) \to {K_{1}}(\mathscr{A})
> \quad \text{and} \quad
> \Phi^{1}_{\mathscr{A}}: {K_{1}}(S(\mathscr{A})) \to {K_{0}}(\mathscr{A})
> $$
>   such that for every C$ ^{*} $-algebraic homomorphism $ \alpha: \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{B} $, the following diagrams commute:
>   $$
> \require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
> {K_{0}}(S(\mathscr{A}))      @>{{K_{0} S}(\alpha)}>> {K_{0}}(S(\mathscr{B})) \\
> @V{\Phi^{0}_{\mathscr{A}}}VV                         @VV{\Phi^{0}_{\mathscr{B}}}V \\
> {K_{1}}(\mathscr{A})         @>>{{K_{1}}(\alpha)}>   {K_{1}}(\mathscr{B})
> \end{CD}
> \quad \quad \quad
> \begin{CD}
> {K_{1}}(S(\mathscr{A}))      @>{{K_{1} S}(\alpha)}>> {K_{1}}(S(\mathscr{B})) \\
> @V{\Phi^{1}_{\mathscr{A}}}VV                         @VV{\Phi^{1}_{\mathscr{B}}}V \\
> {K_{0}}(\mathscr{A})         @>>{{K_{0}}(\alpha)}>   {K_{0}}(\mathscr{B})
> \end{CD}
> $$
>   Suppose further that $ \Phi^{0}_{\mathbb{C}} $ and $ \Phi^{1}_{\mathbb{C}} $ are isomorphisms. Then prove that $ \Phi^{0}_{\mathscr{A}} $ and $ \Phi^{1}_{\mathscr{A}} $ are isomorphisms for every C$ ^{*} $-algebra $ \mathscr{A} $.

Wegge-Olsen’s hint is to consider the commutative diagrams above for the homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\alpha: \mathbb{C} & \to     \mathscr{A} \otimes \mathbb{K}; \\
        1          & \mapsto p \otimes e_{11},
\end{align*}
where $ p $ is a fixed choice of a projection in $ \mathscr{A} $ and $ e_{11} $ is a rank-$ 1 $ projection in $ \mathbb{K} \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} {M_{\infty}}(\mathbb{C}) $.

---

**My difficulty:**

I do not see how
\begin{align*}
{K_{0}}(\alpha):   & {K_{0}}(\mathbb{C})    \to {K_{0}}(\mathscr{A} \otimes \mathbb{K}), \\
{K_{1}}(\alpha):   & {K_{1}}(\mathbb{C})    \to {K_{1}}(\mathscr{A} \otimes \mathbb{K}), \\
{K_{0} S}(\alpha): & {K_{0}}(S(\mathbb{C})) \to {K_{0}}(S(\mathscr{A} \otimes \mathbb{K}))
\quad \text{and} \\
{K_{1} S}(\alpha): & {K_{1}}(S(\mathbb{C})) \to {K_{1}}(S(\mathscr{A} \otimes \mathbb{K}))
\end{align*}
are isomorphisms. If this hurdle can be overcome, then $ \Phi^{0}_{\mathscr{A}} $ and $ \Phi^{1}_{\mathscr{A}} $ are clearly isomorphisms.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: Obviously, $K_0(\alpha)$ and the rest of the mappings are not isomorphisms. Because otherwise it would imply that all $C^\ast$-algebras have isomorphic $K_0$-groups (and $K_1$-groups). My guess is that he has shown that the suspension functor is surjective. Then using the above technique he tries to show that the suspension is injective as well.

Answer (score 3):

A vague guess:

Consider something by putting your two Diagramms together (for the map $\alpha:\mathbf{C} \rightarrow A$) so that they fuse to one diagram with three lines. In the first diagram you replace $A$ by $S(A)$ so that double Suspension $SS(A)$ is involved.

The first column is then an isomorphism $K_0(SS(\mathbf{C}) \cong K_0(\mathbf{C})$.

Chase in the Diagramm, to see that the second column is also something (a isomorphism (??!)) for the subgroup generated by $[p]$. Then vary over all $p$.

Maybe something like this.. or a starting Point to think further.

Comment: I was thinking about this problem too. Following the suggestion in this answer, I think I can get the surjectivity of $\Phi^0_A$ and $\Phi^1_A$ for all $A$, but I couldn't figure out the injectivity.