# reference for KK theory

Tags: reference-request, noncommutative-geometry, kk-theory

I wanted to ask you, if you have any good references (book or pdf) to learn about the KK theroy of Kasparov. I think the presentation of Blackadar is too close from the commutative theory.

I was searching for a C* proof of the Bott periodicity and arrived [in this thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131763/the-right-c-algebraic-proof-of-bott-periodicity/131797#131797). I searched in the references mentionned there but I didn't find anything about KK theory.

Any advice ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to learn more about KK-theory there is a book by Kjeld Knudsen Jensen and Klaus Thomsen with the title "Elements of KK-theory". You can have a look there.

I would also recommend those surveys:
http://www.personal.psu.edu/ndh2/math/Papers_files/Higson%20-%201990%20-%20A%20primer%20on%20KK-theory.pdf

https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.3802